# Focus on ngselect on empty using directives

Tags: angular

I have a template driven form.In the form there is a mandatory field for a ng-select dropdown and a textbox.When I press submit method

1. if the ng-select-dropdown is empty focus should go to ng-select
   dropdown.
2. If the ng-select is selected then if the textbox is empty
   then the focus should go to the textbox.
   This I have implemented using directive.I have achieved the second one (ng-select is selected then if the textbox is empty then the focus should go to the textbox). But I'm not able to achieve the first condition.

I have added a sample stackblitz link below for your reference.In this focus works on select.The same thing I need to implement using ng-select.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-focusonerror?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

**Directive**

```
 @HostListener('submit')
  onFormSubmit() {
    let invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');
    if (invalidControl) {
      invalidControl.focus();
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-focusonerror?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have added a stackblitz link.This same thing has to be achieved by removing select.Instead of that ng-select has to be used.When you press submit it should automatically focus the ng-select

Comment: Hi chellappan.you said you could solve this error using component instance can u tell me how can I achieve that?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I have multiple ng-select.since u have used content-child I got only the first ng-select reference always which is incorrect.I didnt get any error.Your code worked correctly for me when I had single ng-select I want to achieve the same thing with multiple ng-selects.I tried ELiseo code but it wasnt working for me.Idk how to use ContentChildren in your code

Comment: I have modifed the stackblitz with multiple ng-select please check:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-custom-focus?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-invalid class will be applied on ng-select, so this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".ng-invalid") will return ng-select tag and it does not have focus method that is why your solution not working.

**Solution:**

Use ContentChild inside FocusonerrorDirective to get NgSelectComponent instance. Then we can call focus method on it somethink like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appFocusonerror]"
})
export class FocusonerrorDirective {
  @ContentChild(NgSelectComponent) select: NgSelectComponent;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener("submit")
  onFormSubmit() {
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".ng-invalid");
    if (invalidControl) {
      if (invalidControl.tagName === "NG-SELECT") {
        this.select.focus();
        return;
      }
      invalidControl.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-custom-focus?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It worked.Can u explain the code

Comment: I'm afraid that the code don't work, you only ask about the first ng-select -You're using `@ContentChild(NgSelectComponent) select: NgSelectComponent;` and this only get the first ng-select. If you has two ng-select and the invalid is the last one, the code don't work

Comment: Yes as per question he has used only one ng-select and if he want to do multiple he can use contentChildren to get all ng-select

Comment: @mohammedfahimullah Since we have placed an appFocusonerror directive on parent form, all the input belongs to the form elements are content children of appFocusonerror  directive. we can query contentchild element or component instance using ContentChild.

Comment: You're ok, I read very fast the question and asked me whats happens with more that one ng-select. NOTE: I love your idea of ask about the "tagName"

Comment: I just realized I have multiple ng-select then what I am supposed to do

Comment: Instead of using ContentChild you can use  @ContentChildren(NgSelectComponent) select: QueryList<NgSelectComponent>; it will return array, You can loop and  call focus method on it.

Answer (score 0):

you need check if your "invalid" has content input inside or not

```
  @HostListener("submit")
  onFormSubmit() {
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".ng-invalid");

    if (invalidControl) {
      //search if is a "complex input"
      const input = invalidControl.querySelector("input");
      if (input) 
        input.focus();
      else {
        invalidControl.focus();
      }
    }
  }
```

NOTE: I don't like very much using querySelector about ng-invalid, so to work-around I like to have a directive

**Update** improve the directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[ngModel],[formControl]"
})
export class NativeElementDirective {
  public el:any
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, @Optional() public control: NgControl, @Optional() select:NgSelectComponent) {
    if (select)
      this.el=select
    else
      this.el=elementRef.nativeElement

  }
}
```

This directive gets all the ngModel or FormControls. If is a ng-select store in "el" the own ng-select, else store the elementRef.nativeElement

So, our FocusonerrorDirective becomes like

```
export class FocusonerrorDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @ContentChildren(NativeElementDirective) controls: QueryList<NativeElementDirective>;
  @HostListener("submit")
  onFormSubmit() {
    const control = this.controls.find(x => x.control.invalid);
    if (control)
      control.el.focus()
  }
}
```

[the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-fbaxjb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I tried to implement your code.Idk for some reason it is not working.Checked your stackblitz it worked for you but not for me.

Comment: If you're using the "directive option" remember include the directive in the `declarations` of your module

Comment: I forked your stackblitz nad work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-focusonerror-pwjpae?file=app%2F_helpers%2Ffocusonerror.directive.ts -just replace your file `focusonerror.directive.ts`by the mine, and add in declarations of app.module.ts the Directive `NativeElementDirective`. If in your real app, your component belong to,e.g. `another.module.ts` remeber that the directive must belong to this module -or if you has a util.module.ts where declare the directive (this module is imported by `another.module.ts` you need **export** the directive too

Comment: When I consoled this.controls value which is present in FocusonErrorDirective I got this but when I consoled your data it was different What am I missing.changes: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
dirty: false
first: undefined
last: undefined
length: 0
_results: []

Comment: Check the versions on ng-select and versions of angular. If use version of Angular 8, you need ng-select v3.0 `npm install --save @ng-select/ng-select@3.0.0` -or in stackblitz in addDependencies: `@ng-select/ng-select@3.0.0`, see the docs: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select. NOTE: Sorry, the link of stackblitz I put in comment was wrong, just corrected

Comment: Im using Angular 9 version.

Comment: Can we implement the same thing in different way.is it possible

Comment: I have many ngIf in the form so will this directive wont work properly?

Comment: This shound'nt happens, only if when you submit makes visible a mat-select and try to reach it. In this case, after makes it visible you need enclosed by a setTimeout() the submit

Comment: Can you show me a practical example for this